# SPARTAN SP601: Why are there two pins associated with one clock?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan

I'm using the Spartan 6 (SP601 Evaluation Board) and was previously using the X2 27MHz Oscillator Clock. However, according to the user manual, there is a faster 200 MHz oscillator (differential) soldered onto the board. I would like to use it, but I am confused why it has two pins associated to it.

Provided below is the table with the clocks and their respective pins on the board. I am currently using the X2 with only one pin, so I have one input called "clk" that is connected to that pin. Could someone explain why there are two pins, "N" and "P" for the U5? How would I include and use this clock in my user constraints file?

[image: Clock Pin Table]

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Perhaps it should be asked on electronics.stackexchange.com where it is on topic.

Comment: shouldn't that be "X2 27MHz"?

Answer (score 2):

From the  [SP601 Hardware  User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug518.pdf), 8. Clock Generation:

> The SP601 has one 2.5V LVDS differential 200 MHz oscillator (U5) soldered onto the board and wired to an FPGA global clock.

From the Wikipedia page [Differential signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling), the section Advantages, suitability for use with low-voltage electronics:

> The electronics industry, particularly in portable and mobile devices, continually strives to lower supply voltage to save power and reduce emitted electromagnetic radiation. A low supply voltage, however, reduces noise immunity. Differential signaling helps to reduce these problems because, for a given supply voltage, it provides twice the noise immunity of a single-ended system.
>
> To see why, ...

Under High-voltage differential signaling:

> ...
>   The generic term High-voltage differential signaling describes a variety of systems. Low-voltage differential signaling or LVDS, on the other hand, is a specific system defined by a TIA/EIA standard.

So the clock is an LVDS clock differentially signaled, the purpose of Low Voltage signaling to reduce power. Differential to add noise immunity.

This doesn't appear to be a programming question and the answer can be determined by simple research.